# Is Denver International Airport (DEN) cannabis-friendly?

Tags: united-states, colorado

Denver International Airport (DEN) has a number of smoking lounges, something I've never seen in any other airport anywhere in the States.

Are those lounges allowed to sell cannabis, since it's now all legal in Colorado?

Comment: This feels more like a travel question than a legal question. Perhaps https://travel.stackexchange.com/ would be a better venue to ask it?

Comment: @Flup, did you try Google?  Apparently, "420-friendly" is 10x more understandable than "cannabis-friendly". :p

Comment: At first I read that as "cannibal-friendly". And, while I suppose the actual question is "better" from a technical perspective, I now want to see how the former question would play out. My smile right now is pretty intense. And it **is** always Friday in Iceland, after all...

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not.  The airport is supposedly under federal jurisdiction (according to a DEN employee), and the federal government does not allow such sales to take place.  Thus, all smoking lounges in DEN are cannabis-free.

Apparently, according to an employee within DEN, some people do manage to get past the security and into those lounges with their own pot, but, they're not allowed to keep at it, either.